# Postgres fulltext search extract matched term

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a search term suggestion mechanism that works with PostgreSQL 11.1. Using GIN index for "search_vector_index" column.

My query so far for returning the matched rows:

```
SELECT "study_collection_collection"."id",
       "study_collection_collection"."name",
       "study_collection_collection"."description",
       "study_collection_collection"."search_vector_index",
       ((0 + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."name", 'my coll')) + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."description", 'my coll')) AS "similarity"
  FROM "study_collection_collection"
 WHERE ("study_collection_collection"."is_public" = true AND ((0 + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."name", 'my coll')) + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."description", 'my coll')) >= 0.1)
 GROUP BY "study_collection_collection"."id", ((0 + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."name", 'my coll')) + SIMILARITY("study_collection_collection"."description", 'my coll'))
 ORDER BY "similarity" DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

**What I actually want**

Get matched terms all over the searched documents based on their frequency. Is this possible in Postgres? If so, how?

note: please don't refer to Lucene, Elasticsearch, Algolia, or other solutions that require a separate technology than Postgres.

Comment: Perhaps [`ts_headline`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE)? It is made for human consumption though.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ts_headline is just to highlight where a specific search term is located inside a document but I don't see how I can use this as it's too specific